# Calculate scalar potential from electric field data in python

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields, potential

I have two 2d arrays of electric field components:

Ex with (256, 512) and Ez with (256, 512) sizes.

I need to calculate scalar potential. Gradient of scalar potential is the electric field vector. So I need the reverse of the gradient.

I tried using the following loop to calculate the potential Φ (phi):

```
nx = 256
nz = 512
phi = np.zeros([nx, nz])

for i in range(1, nz):
    phi[:, i] = -dx * Ex[:, i-1] + phi[:, i-1]
    for j in range(1, nx):
        phi[j, :] = -dz * Ez[j-1, :] + phi[j-1, :]
```

This gives me an ok but weird Φ (these vertical lines are suspicious):
I am suspicious of these vertical lines. Does anyone have any ideas?
[image]

It suppose to look like this
[image]

Comment: We cannot see what suspicious vertical lines you are talking about.

Comment: I don't know the exact issue, but seems that somehow it's due to overlapping lines/rows in calculation. If you will assign values from a fixed index instead from a whole range,- like when change code parts to ```Ex[0, i-1]``` and ```Ez[j-1, 0]```, then chart will be a lot smoother, but I don't know if semantics will be left the same, i.e. if you will get the required plot output. If you would supply full Python code in the question and your Ex,Ez array data in the form of text files attached or something - somebody would help you more.